# Clicked "guest session" , system restarted, and now I'm stuck at a black screen

Tags: login, users

I accidentally clicked the "guest" user profile and my system restarted itself, and now I can't get past a black screen with only the mouse pointer visible. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: Did you restart the system?

Comment: Do a boot recovery, enter fsck option and run it. Maybe some corrupted file.

Comment: Based on your description, in particular the part about how the mouse pointer is visible, I think [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears) may help.

Answer (score 3):

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and you will be taken to a command line terminal.
- Enter your user name and password to log in to your installed system.
- Type: `sudo systemctl stop lightdm`
- Type: `sudo systemctl start lightdm`
- You should now be taken to the Display Manager's login screen where you can select your session type and user account.
- In case you get lost, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to be taken back to the graphical system
- If this does not work, if you manage to go past steps 1 and 2, run `reboot` to reboot your system.

Comment: Few notes: Instead of using stop and start, the user can use `sudo systemctl restart lightdm`.  The required password is not the root one, but the user password.

Comment: Thanks, got mixed up a bit there and I corrected the response about the password.